# How many permutations of 4 letters can be made out of the letters of the word 'examination'?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

[as stated in the title]

[n-p-n-p-n-p]

Comment: Why not write down how you did the job? then we can help to see where you missed something

Comment: Use cases (i) all different; (ii) one double; (iii) two doubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *examination* has $11$ letters.  It is composed of $8$ different letters, $3$ of which repeat once.

As Andre suggests, break it down into three cases.

1. **All different.**  Choose the four letters out of the eight you'll use ${8 \choose 4}$, and then order them ($4!$).
2. **One double.**  Choose which of the three letters is the double ${3 \choose 1}$, then choose which positions they go in the word ${4 \choose 2}$.  Then, choose the two remaining letters ${7 \choose 2}$, and decide which goes first and which goes second in the remaining two spaces ($2!$).
3. **Two doubles.**  Choose which two of the three doubled letters to use ${3 \choose 2}$, then order them ($6$).

Adding all of these gives $2454$.

Answer (score 6):

We could also use generating functions *(which has recently been my favorite method since I suck at identifying cases)*.

Consider the multiset $M=[1\text{E}, 1\text{X}, 2\text{A}, 1\text{M}, 2\text{I}, 2\text{N}, 1\text{T}, 1\text{O}]$.

The number of $4$-permutations of $M$ is the coefficient of $x^4/4!$ in the exponential expansion of

$$(1+x)^5 \left(1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}\right)^3.$$

The coefficient of $x^4$ above is $409/4$. Multiplying by $4!$ we get $2454$.

---

The $(1+x)$ represent the letters that are not repeated, while $(1+x+x^2/2)$ represents those letters that are repeated twice.

Comment: Very cool.  I'm going to need to learn about these generating-function things.